# Android Tab Fragments Nullpointerexception at addTabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I was following a tutorial to create Tabs using fragments in the following link

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

I have got nullpointerException at the getContentView() in the source code of TabHost (something to do with the creation of view) that traces back to this line.

```
     CQActivity.addTabs(this, this.tabHost, this.tabHost.newTabSpec("urls").setIndicator("URLQ"), tabInfo = new TabInfo("urls", URLQFragment.class, savedInstanceState));
```

addTabs() is as shown

```
private static void addTabs(CQActivity activity, TabHost tabhost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo){
    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
    String tag = tabSpec.getTag();
    tabInfo.fragment = activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);

    if(tabInfo.fragment != null && !tabInfo.fragment.isDetached()){
        FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(tabInfo.fragment);
        ft.commit();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
    tabhost.addTab(tabSpec);
}
```

Also I inflated the fragments - a sample fragment looks like this

public class FileqFragment extends Fragment {

```
public FileqFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(container == null){
        return null;
    }
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fileq, container, false);
}
```

}

And all the xml is as shown

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>            

          </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>       
</LinearLayout>
```

Tabhost is initialized as shown

```
     tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost1);
     tabHost.setup();
     TabInfo tabInfo = null;
```

-

```
01-01 20:17:51.262: E/AndroidRuntime(824): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testq/com.example.testq.CQActivity}: 
.
.
java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 20:17:51.262: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 20:17:51.262: E/AndroidRuntime(824): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 20:17:51.262: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.widget.TabHost$FactoryContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:720)
01-01 20:17:51.262: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
01-01 20:17:51.262: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
01-01 20:17:51.262: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.example.testq.CQActivity.addTabs(CQActivity.java:105)
01-01 20:17:51.262: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.example.testq.CQActivity.initializeTabHost(CQActivity.java:53)
01-01 20:17:51.262: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.example.testq.CQActivity.onCreate(CQActivity.java:43)
```

Comment: I added it please check now

Comment: Thats where he is calling addTab.

Answer (score 0):

**try the following:**

```
//Main Activity
package com.example.tabhostexample;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    private TabHost tabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabHost = getTabHost();

        TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
        TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
        TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third tab");

        tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
        tab1.setContent(new Intent(this, Tab1Activity.class));
        tab2.setIndicator("Tab2");
        tab2.setContent(new Intent(this, Tab2Activity.class));
        tab3.setIndicator("Tab3");
        tab3.setContent(new Intent(this, Tab3Activity.class));

        tabHost.addTab(tab1);
        tabHost.addTab(tab2);
        tabHost.addTab(tab3);
    }
}

//Tab1Activity
package com.example.tabhostexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Tab1Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab1);
    }
}

//Tab2Activity
package com.example.tabhostexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Tab2Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab2);
    }
}

//Tab3Activity
package com.example.tabhostexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Tab3Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab3);
    }
}
```